# ¿Cómo cambiar el número índice del array por su nombre?

Tags: laravel, api

Estoy montando una respuesta a una llamada api de laravel para mostrar las entradas del blog y el usuario que la ha escrito. Necesito mostrar el nombre de los 2 objetos que incluyo en el array, en la primera respuesta salen bien y en las siguientes salen números. Necesito que todo se muestre como la primera respuesta

`entry: {datos}, user:{datos}`

Y no sé porque no sigue poniéndole el nombre como le marco en el controlador.

Mi controlador:

```
    public function all_entries ( ApiEntryRequest $request )
{

    $entries = Entry::orderBy('date', 'DESC')->get();


    $dates_entry = array();

    foreach ( $entries as $entry) {

        $user = User::where('id', '=', $entry->user_id )->first();

        $dates_entry['entry'] = $entry;
        $dates_entry['user']= $user;

        array_push($dates_entry, $dates_entry['entry'], $dates_entry['user']);
    }

    if ($entries) {
        return $this->prepareResult(true, $dates_entry, [], "Entries All");
    }
    else{
        return $this->prepareResult(true, '', [], "No Entry");
    }

}
```

Y la respuesta json:

```
"data": {
    "entry": {
       "datos" : "valor"
    },
    "user": {
         "datos" : "valor"
    },
    "0": {
       "datos" : "valor"
    },
    "1": {
       "datos" : "valor"
    },
    "2": {
       "datos" : "valor"
    },
```

Cualquier ayuda la agradezco. He estado buscando pero no encuentro ninguna respuesta.

Comment: Es multidimensional `$dates_entry['entry']["datos"];` puede que funcione

Comment: De esa forma, si tenés 1000 `Entry` en la base de datos vas a hacer 1001 consultas. Por qué no haces que la consulta traiga las `Entry` con su `User` relacionado. Luego lo de mapear la respuesta se puede hacer de varias formas, parece más para un [Api Resource](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources), pero puede mapearse con un foreach también.

Comment: La respuesta json es correcta segun el codigo que muestras. Pero no entiendo del todo, como ya tienes `entry` y `user` en el json, no podrás tener mas propiedades con el mismo nombre. Podrias publicar como debe de lucir el json de salida correcta.

Comment: Los datos son correctos, solo que debería salir siempre entry y user, en ver de luego los números:

"data": {
    "entry": {
       "datos" : "valor"
    },
    "user": {
         "datos" : "valor"
    },
  "entry": {
       "datos" : "valor"
    },
    "user": {
         "datos" : "valor"
    },
  "entry": {
       "datos" : "valor"
    },
    "user": {
         "datos" : "valor"
    },
}

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví:

```
        foreach ( $entries as $entry) {

        $user = User::where('id', '=', $entry->user_id )->first();

        $dates_entry2 = [
            'entry' => $entry,
            'user'  => $user
        ];

        array_push($dates_entry, $dates_entry2);
    }
```

Comment: Te sugerimos agregar que realizaste , revisa [answer], saludos.